# Chrome play only 10 html5 video on one page

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I streaming h264 video with `gstreamer` and try to play it from Chrome. I create simple html

```
<body>
  <video style="width:20%;" class="current" src="http://ip:port" autoplay>
  </video>
  ...
  34 more
</body>
```

but chrome play only first 10 videos, in other 24 just black box. All streams work fine, I can delete first 10 videos from html and chrome will show me only next 10 videos.

Is there any limitation in Chrome?

Comment: You want to autoplay 34 or 35 videos _on a single page_?

Comment: @enhzflep, yep. We used vlc plugin and it worked fine, but I think that html5 will be more lightweight.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the word light-weight figures into a discussion that involves a page with 35 videos playing simultaneously, other than to say "it will never be light-weight". I'd love to see the memory consumption for such a thing. Phones would have a fit.. I'm often short-sighted, but can see no reasonable solution to any problem that involved such an idea. It sounds as awful for a user as a form with hundreds of check-boxes or a list-view (select element) with 10s of thousands of options. None of these elements have been designed to be (ab)used in such a fashion.

Comment: @enhzflep, it's just a video surveillance system with a grid of 6x6, it's not big deal.

Comment: As I said: "I'm often short-sighted" - oh well, time to add another instance to the list. Thanks, I appreciate the background info. :) Hope the VLC plugin proves suitable.